# Populate empty table with data from other tables based on dropdown list selection

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have several tables in one tab which I have named individually. In another tab I have a table that I wish to populate with the same information of the selected table based on a drop down selection. All tables are the same size. The dropdown is also a named range.

The list in the dropdown is the name of each table.
The following is my approach but I'm off by a row. 'PRCoverage' is the name of the dropdown.

`=INDEX(INDIRECT(PRCoverage),ROW()-ROW($B$7),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$7))`

The issue is that the tables don't all start in the same row. I'm trying to figure out to way to reference the first row in each table.

Comment: please remember to select as correct answer if it helps, noticed that you have not done that in past

Comment: @actuario99 can you please update this to show the solution that worked? If you have your own solution that you used, please post that and select it as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I've put everything onto one sheet for screenshots, this will work across multiple pages.

[image]

1. I began by having a list I could use for a drop down list in cell `F1`. This is the named range in `D2:D3` called `TableList`. Once I had this name, that is how cell `F1` validates.
2. Next, you will see in the formula in `F1` that I have two named ranges. These are *dynamic* named ranges. To create them: Select cell `F1`, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open the name manager. Then select the "New" button. For this demonstration I named it `Male_Characters`. For the formula I used: `=Sheet1!A3` **Please note I am not using absolute references (no "$")**. Repeat this for the starting corner of every table you want to display.
3. Finally, create a nested if statement that works through each table as you can see in my screen shot. `=IF($F$1=$A$1,Male_Characters,IF($F$1=$A$12,Female_Characters,""))` is the same code in all the cells of my display table.

Sample Spreadsheet: [Click Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak6r9nlUd1ZOjPAJWUMkueURA3V42g)

Comment: Note: I prefer this method to using any `INDIRECT` functions, because `INDIRECT` breaks so easily.

Comment: +1 because this is an interesting approach, any change to placement of tables breaks this method...then again any change to name of tables breaks mine.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think that moving mine would break it, that's why I avoided the "INDIRECT" function. I've had poor luck with everything breaking and going to hell as soon as I moved something.
Let me try moving mine now :)
Edit: you are absolutely correct. It definitely breaks if you move it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can get the in which entries of particular start with something like the following:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(MyDropDown))
```

I then use `OFFSET` to fill my `TABLE`

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & ROW(INDIRECT(MyDropDown))),ROW()-2,COLUMN()-1)
```

But you can just as easily swap `OFFSET` for `INDEX`

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & ROW(INDIRECT(MyDropDown))),ROW()-2,COLUMN()-1)
```

[image]

[image]